# Выполнение формы во фрейме

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли выполнить POST форму, которая ссылается на сторонний сайт, во фрейме?
Например, форму оплаты PayPal:

```html
<form id="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="display: block;">
  <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="funds01">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="admin">
  <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="example@yandex.ru">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@yandex.ru">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
  <button type="submit">Go to payment</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено!

```
<form action="site.com" target="iframe name">
</form>

<iframe name="iframe name"></iframe>
```

Результат отправки формы откроется в задданом фрейме